# Static variable is empty while retrieving from fragment, working on the other fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, retrofit2

The static variable is created in the Main activity and a value is assigned to it. The value is retrieving from the historyFragment but is null when retrieving from homeFragment, which is the default fragment to load on the Main activity.[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KJi0y.png)[Main Activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DNNoW.png)[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iSZLs.png)[History Fragment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w7wbr.png)[Home fragment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jg627.png)

Answer (score 1):

Aryan It's hard to understand the execution order of your code, but I suppose when you try to assign user variable in HomeFragment (in row 51), MainActivity has no user value yet.

It's bad practice to share data between screens by static fields because the data in static fields can be removed after Activity recreation and static field will have a null value.
So I can recommend you to read about MVP, MVVM, Clean Architecture, etc.
As a quick solution, I can recommend you to send data from activity to fragment via Bundle.

Comment: I was using navigation drawer to navigate between the fragments. And the homeFragment is the default fragment to load at the beginning. So how am I supposed to create a variable that can be accessible from all other fragments including the homeFragment when it is created at the beginning.